# JWindow placement at screen center on Linux Debian XFCE

Tags: java, linux, xfce, jwindow

This is my first question, so i apologize in case i make any mistake.

My problem is this:

I have a Java application running on a *Linux Debian (Wheezy)* machine which uses *XFCE* as window manager.
When the application creates a page (which extends *JWindow*) that has x=0 and y=0 as location coordinates, the window is always placed at the center of the screen.

What i'd need is that windows with location (0,0) would be placed at the top left corner of the screen instead of the center.

The only solution i found so far is to set the location of those windows to (1,0) or (0,1);

Does anyone know how to solve this problem and if it is resolvable using Java code?